# Finding a value in an array of arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array in the following format

```
var persons : [[String]] = []

let blah : [String] = [title, firstName, lastName, address1, town, postCode]

persons.append(blah)
```

Which gives output like :

```
[
   ["Mr", "Joe", "Bloggs", "999 Letsbe Avenue", "Townsville", "TS12 9UY"],
   ["Mr", "Peter", "Smith", "999 Underavest", "CityVille", "OP19 1IK"]
]
```

I want to do a search to find the first occurrence of "Smith" but I'm stumped on how to do it.

Any help please?

Comment: warning: Using arrays to model records like this is a bad idea, and will only lead you down a road of incorrect-index errors, type casting headaches and pain. It's better to use a `struct` or `class` to model your `Person`. At that point, the search becomes as easy and readable as `people.first(where: { $0.lastName == "Smith })`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
if let index = persons.index(where:{ $0.contains("Smith")  }) { 
     print(index)  
}
```

Btw it's better to have

```
 struct Person {
    let fname,lname,address:String
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect! Do you know how I can get the row number of the matching entry?  like if I search for "Smith" I get 2, and if I search for "Bloggs" I get 1 ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, that's all been perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
let array = [
       ["Mr", "Joe", "Bloggs", "999 Letsbe Avenue", "Townsville", "TS12 9UY"],
       ["Mr", "Peter", "Smith", "999 Underavest", "CityVille", "OP19 1IK"]
    ]
    
    var index = array.flatMap { $0 }.firstIndex(of: "Smith")
    print("\(index!/5)")
     index = array.flatMap { $0 }.firstIndex(of: "Bloggs")
    print("\(index!/5)")
```

I have taken 5 to find the index as there are five entries in each array.

[image]

Comment: You can use `enumerated()` to directly get the indices, rather than this flatMap + division trick (which will break the moment somebody adds/removes a field to the people's fields)